# Select records having appointment date exactly after 12 hours from current datetime

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I want to select all the records from database table whose date time(AppointmentDate column) is equal to current date time + 12 hours.

so basically the records having appointment date which are exactly after 12 hours from current datetime.

how can we write this query in linq to entites?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How precise do you expect "current datetime" to be?  You do realize that this is probably not possible at millisecond precision and depdnding on what you are doing, maybe not at second precision.  Your task doing the work can take long enough that the selected items are now less than 12 hours away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty straight forward:

```
var twelveHoursFromNow = DateTime.Now.AddHours(12);
db.Records.Where(m => m.AppointmentDate == twelveHoursFromNow);
```

However, the equal may be a bit restrictive. As `DateTime.Now` could be 12:45:30am causing you to discard an appointment at 12:45:00pm. More likely than not, you're going to want a range.

```
db.Records.Where(m => m.AppointmentDate > rangeStartDateTime && m.AppointmentDate < rangeEndDateTime);
```